# Calling wxQueueEvent causes segmentation fault

Tags: wxwidgets

I have just started exploring wxWidgets. I have a main class and a thread that accepts incoming TCP connections. When data is available on the connection I want to post an event for the main thread to handle the data. Here is some code to show what I'm doing.

```
// My wxFrame class 
class VisorFrame : public wxFrame
{
  public:
    VisorFrame(wxFrame* frame, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
    virtual ~VisorFrame(){};
}

VisorFrame::VisorFrame(wxFrame* frame, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size) :
    wxFrame(frame, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size)
{
    // create thread to handle TCP connections
    networkThread = new NetworkThread(this->GetEventHandler(), mutexKeepRunning, &keepRunning, mutexCond, cond);
}

This is what I have in my event table:

EVT_THREAD(ID_ProcClientCmd, VisorFrame::OnProcessClientCmd)

// My worker thread class
class NetworkThread : public wxThread
{
    public:
    NetworkThread(wxEvtHandler* parent, wxMutex* mutexKeepRunning, bool* keepRunning, wxMutex* mutexCond, wxCondition* cond);
}

NetworkThread::NetworkThread(wxEvtHandler* parent, wxMutex* mutexKeepRunning, bool* keepRunning, wxMutex* mutexCond, wxCondition* cond)  :
        mutexKeepRunning(mutexKeepRunning), keepRunning(keepRunning), mutexCond(mutexCond), cond(cond)
{
}

// This is how I post my event inside my Thread class:

    if (parent != NULL)
    {
        wxThreadEvent event(wxEVT_THREAD, ID_ProcClientCmd);
        event.SetPayload((void *) pkt_info);
        wxQueueEvent(parent, event.Clone());
    }
    else
        wxPuts(_("NetworkThread: parent is NULL"));
```

When wxQueueEvent() gets called it throws segmentation fault. I looked at the sampled/thread.cpp code and observed that it calls wxQueueEvent() with a wxFrame pointer. When I try doing the same thing, it won't compile because wxQueueEvent expects a wxEvtHandler* as the first arg.

What am I doing wrong that is causing this seg fault?
Thanks for your help

Comment: what is parent in your code? How it is declared/defined? What is a backtrack at the time of the crash?

Comment: I have updated my post to include parent's declaration/definition. How do I generate a backtrace?

Comment: why do you use `this->GetEventHandler()`? Just use `this`. `wxFrame` is `wxEvtHandler`. What compiler/IDE do you use?

Comment: I changed this->GetEventHandler() to just this, and now it mostly works. I say mostly, because twice my app froze after I posted the event. 

I'm use Visual Code on Mac and build the code using Makefile

Comment: `(void *) pkt_info` does pkt_info variable heap or stack allocated?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this part:

> ```
>     wxThreadEvent event(wxEVT_THREAD, ID_ProcClientCmd);
>     event.SetPayload((void *) pkt_info);
>     wxQueueEvent(parent, event.Clone());
> ```

`wxQueueEvent` calls `wxEvtHandler::QueueEvent()` and the [documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#acffd03bf407a856166ea71ef0318b59a) for that method states:

> this method takes ownership of the event parameter, i.e. it will
> delete it itself

So you should create the event with the `new` operator use that pointer like so:

```cpp
    wxThreadEvent* event = new wxThreadEvent(wxEVT_THREAD, ID_ProcClientCmd);
    event->SetPayload((void *) pkt_info);
    wxQueueEvent(parent, event);
```

Comment: `event.Clone()` should not this create a proper copy surviving the stack?

Comment: I don't think so (at least it's not documented as doing so).  Clone is only [documented](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_thread_event.html#af8d1c4ec499415d84680c1a52a68513a) as making a deep copy of the event.  In particular that means that the string members of the cloned event are full copies instead of referring to the original string's buffer.

Comment: Sure but referring to the documentation for `wxEvtHandler::QueueEvent()`, it uses a stack allocated thread event and then queues it with evt.Clone().

Comment: Looking at the source code for wxThreadEvent::Clone, it does just return `new wxThreadEvent(*this)`.  So this probably isn't the source of the problem after all.  As you said above, the lifetime of pkt_info is a possibility for the cause of the segfault.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem turned out to be on my side. I was overwriting the parent and corrupting it, leading to seg fault